# VSTS Test result update API is not working

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

Hi iam using VSTS test management APIS for upating test results.

First iam using {collection name}/{projectname}/_apis/test/runs/{result id}/results?api-version=2.0-preview

with JSON value

```
[{"testResult":{"id":100000},"testCase":{"id":417},"priority":1,"outcome":"Failed","testPoint":{"id":51},"state":"Completed ","associatedWorkItems":[452]}]
```

all works fine suddenly it will updated test result but work item bug is not linked with test result.

When i use 3.0-preview

```
[{"id":100000,"outcome":"Failed","state":"Completed ","associatedBugs":[199,200]}]
```

Still not working

What iam using wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It seems both for [results REST API](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/test/results#update-test-results-for-a-test-run) and [results (1.0) REST API](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/test/results_1_0#update-test-results-for-a-test-run), bugs can not be linked by updating test results for a test run.

I reported [Update test results for a test run REST API can not link bugs](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/205614/update-test-results-for-a-test-run-rest-api-can-no.html) for it, you can follow up.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. Can't see any progress on the above reported issue. Have you found any solution to get it working?